# Dual connections, bracket

Tags: differential-geometry, almost-complex

If $\nabla$ is a torsionfree connection and $(\nabla_{X}J)Y=(\nabla_{Y}J)X$, J- an almost complex structure, and $\nabla_{X}^{*}Y:=J\nabla_{X}(JY)$ its dual connecion. Is it correct to conclude that $[X,Y]=0$?

Comment: Could precise your question ? I don't understand why you introduced the dual connection

Comment: For example, this is the case in special Kaehler manifolds, $\nabla $ exists and $\nabla ^{*}$ is defined it that way. So, if one wants to study submanifolds in special Kaehler manifolds, must work with both connections, things get pretty complicated.

Comment: Yes but i don't understand why it is relevant to introduce the dual connection to answer your question. By the way, do you assume any hypothesis of compatibility for $J$ ?

Comment: Because I got $[X,Y]=0$ using $\nabla^{*}$, just interchanging $X$ and $Y$ and subtracting. This is valid on special Kaehlerian manifolds: $g(X,Y):=\omega(X,JY)$ and $\nabla\omega =0$, $g$ is a Riemannian metric and $\omega $ is a symplectic form.